# c# Configuration class and KeyVault

Tags: c#, configuration, azure-keyvault

I just need this clarifying for me, maybe someone has had a similar situation and come up with a decent solution.
Currently we store all our sensitive data in **ApplicationSettings** which is not great.
And from the application settings we use **Autofac** to create a singleton **Configuration** class that is then injected into any class that requires any of the settings.

This is what the class currently looks like:

```
public class CormarConfig : ICormarConfig
{
    public bool Live => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"].ToUpper().Equals("LIVE");
    public string SqlConnectionString => ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ToString();
    public string OracleConnectionString => ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConnection"].ToString();

    public connectionType ConnectionType => Live ? connectionType.Live : connectionType.Test;
    public string CollectionManagerEndpoint => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CollectionManagerEndpoint"];
    public string TradePortalUrl => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TradePortalUrl"];
    public string TroposDb => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TroposDatabase" ];
    public string WmsBaseEndpoint => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WmsBaseEndpoint"];

    /// ------- Removed from brevity ------- ///

}
```

So, now we moved a lot of these sensitive settings into azure **Key Vault** which is good. I then created a simple class for retrieving these "secrets" like this:

```
public class SecretProvider : ISecretProvider
{
    private readonly KeyVaultClient _keyVaultClient;
    private readonly ISecretConfig _config;

    public SecretProvider(ISecretConfig config)
    {
        var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
        _keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(
            new KeyVaultClient.AuthenticationCallback(azureServiceTokenProvider.KeyVaultTokenCallback));
        _config = config;
    } 

    public async Task<string> GetAsync(string name)
    {
        var secret = await _keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync($"{_config.KeyVaultEndPoint}/secrets/{name}");
        return secret.Value;
    }
}
```

I have tested this and it works fine.
The problem is I now what to replace some of the **Properties** in my **CormarConfig** class.

For example, I would like to do something like:

```
private readonly ISecretProvider _secretProvider;
public CormarConfig(ISecretProvider secretProvider) => _secretProvider = secretProvider;

private string _sqlConnectionString;
public async Task<string> GetSqlConnectionString()
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_sqlConnectionString)) return _sqlConnectionString;
    _sqlConnectionString = await _secretProvider.GetAsync("DefaultConnection");
    return _sqlConnectionString;
}
```

Would this be an acceptable solution?

Comment: Would it not be easier just to encrypt the AppSettings section of your config file?

Answer (score 0):

> Would this be an acceptable solution?

Yes. However, the `CormarConfig` you provided is a class, maybe some method is concise by you. So, I suggest you add a `CormarConfig` Constructor in `CormarConfig` class as below:

```
public CormarConfig(ISecretProvider secretProvider) => _secretProvider = secretProvider;
```

Comment: I am lost, that is literally the fist line of the example I have shown :o